# When to use multiple parts for a mesh, and when to build detail in?

Tags: 3d, models, 3d-meshes

I am always running into the decision whether or not to make a mesh one connected mesh or to add small details as just separate parts to the model. Is there a best practices for this? Does it matter for games either way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fewer meshes equate to fewer draw calls, so generally you should try to go for as few as possible.

Split them when:

- one mesh would be so large that you'd need 32-bit index buffers to address (as this is generally *too* large)
- the sub-mesh uses different textures/shaders/materials
- the sub-mesh is somehow optional and might be detached or attached from the main mesh often (or similar reasons; basically you want to avoid having to update the main mesh's vertex buffer)

Comment: And what about the gains of a multi-part mesh in terms of allowing partial occlusion culling? I mean, in case all sub-parts are highpoly, couldn't it be peformant to cull mesh sub-parts that are occluded?

Comment: Yes, but LOD systems will also factor in there as well. It's a balancing act.